# How to set maximum allowed CPUs per job in Slurm?

Tags: slurm

How can I set the maximum number of CPUs each job can ask for in Slurm?

We're running a GPU cluster and want a sensible number of CPUs to be always available for GPU jobs. This is kind of fine as long as the job asks for GPUs because there's GPU <-> CPU mapping in the `gres.conf`. But this doesn't stop a job that doesn't ask for any GPUs not to acquire all CPUs in the system.

Answer (score 1):

To set the maximum number of CPUs a single job can use, at the cluster level, you can run the following command:

```
sacctmgr modify cluster <cluster_name> set maxtresperjob=cpu=<nb of CPUs>
```

Note that you must have `SelectType=select/cons_tres` in your configuration file for this to work.

Alternatively the same restriction can be applied partition-wise, QOS-wise, account-wise, etc.